# No propertes through config server on browser

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

```
http://localhost:8888/configserver/default
```

response:

```
{"name":"configserver","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":"2e06363687594606c88802af5682da972955bec7","state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

Properties file git folder:
/home/user/workspace/backend/git-logspateconfig

Has 2 files:

1. Accounting.properties and logspate-config.properties, same content.

> ```
> accounting.maxInstances=10000
> accounting.minInstances=10
> ```

configserver project (@EnableConfigServer and @SpringBootApplication) has following files:

```
spring.application.name=configserver
server.port=8888

#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///home/user/workspace/backend/git-logspateconfig
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master

# Custom HTTP configurations for Git repository access
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///home/user/workspace/backend/git-logspateconfig
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skipSslValidation=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=nkrishnawat
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=_lF2LT4MzKaY5i0OLDlDN1QwLQD4jNr4dfARZ
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
```

Why I am not getting value in response, No error on server console.

Answer (score 0):

Properties Files Naming Convention: Spring Cloud Config Server by default looks for properties files named after the application name and the profile, separated by a hyphen. For example, if your application name is configserver and you're using the default profile, the properties file should be named configserver-default.properties or configserver-default.yml. - From CHATGpt